# How to aggregate timeseries data based on end time and start time difference from difference rows?

Tags: pandas, time-series

I have a data set which looks like this

| startTime | endTime | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-06-14T23:20:03.182Z | 2021-06-14T23:23:39.113Z | A |
| 2021-06-14T23:26:27.226Z | 2021-06-14T23:52:59.752Z | A |
| 2021-06-14T23:52:18.720Z | 2021-06-14T23:52:18.720Z | B |
| 2021-06-14T23:54:14.582Z | 2021-06-14T23:54:40.218Z | B |
| 2021-06-14T23:55:59.752Z | 2021-06-14T23:58:59.752Z | A |

I want to aggregate the data based on the difference between the endTime for a particular name and startTime in the next rows when the name is same within 1 hour. So, I want to create a table like this

| startTime | endTime | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-06-14T23:20:03.182Z | 2021-06-14T23:58:59.752Z | A |
| 2021-06-14T23:52:18.720Z | 2021-06-14T23:54:40.218Z | B |

I am a beginner in python and have no clue how to approach this problem. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Would you consider an additional entry of name A with start time at 2021-06-15 00:05 which is within one hour from last end time of A (but at different clock hour) to be aggregated together with the previous entries or as a new group ?

Comment: Another question:  Is it possible that for one aggregated entry, the time duration between startTime and endTime be more than 1 hour ?  This could happen if you have 3 entries in the original dataframe where for the same name we have each entry being 40 minutes apart.  So, the total duration will be more than 1 hour if we aggregate the 3 entries altogether.  Should we aggregate all 3 entries, or just aggregate the first 2 and leaving the third entry in a separate grouping ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`groupby agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html#pandas-core-groupby-dataframegroupby-aggregate) on both `Name` and [`pd.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html#pandas-grouper) hourly then get the min and max time for the hour per name:

Convert `startTime` and `endTime` to datetime if not already:

```
df['startTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['startTime'])
df['endTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['endTime'])
```

Thanks to [@SeaBean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68032911/how-to-aggregate-timeseries-data-based-on-end-time-and-start-time-difference-fro/68033035#comment120248312_68033035) endTime should me maximal within an hour from the min start time per Name:

```
# Transform startTime to the min per group
df['startTime'] = df.groupby('Name')['startTime'].transform('min')
# Get duration for end times vs min start time per group
df['dur'] = df['endTime'] - df['startTime']

# Filter out outside an hour from initial start
df = df[df['dur'].between(pd.Timedelta(hours=0), pd.Timedelta(hours=1))]

# Get Max duration per Name after filtering invalid options
df = df.loc[
    df.groupby('Name')['dur'].idxmax(),
    ['startTime', 'endTime', 'Name']
].reset_index(drop=True)
```

`df`:

```
                         startTime                          endTime Name
0 2021-06-14 23:20:03.182000+00:00 2021-06-14 23:58:59.752000+00:00    A
1 2021-06-14 23:52:18.720000+00:00 2021-06-14 23:54:40.218000+00:00    B
```

Optional Convert back to original format:

```
fmt_str = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'
new_df['startTime'] = new_df['startTime'].dt.strftime(fmt_str)
new_df['endTime'] = new_df['endTime'].dt.strftime(fmt_str)
```

```
                     startTime                      endTime Name
0  2021-06-14T23:20:03.182000Z  2021-06-14T23:58:59.752000Z    A
1  2021-06-14T23:52:18.720000Z  2021-06-14T23:54:40.218000Z    B
```

---

Original answer which got the min and max start and end times within the same hour per Name per hour:

```
# Get Min Time Per Hour
starts = (
    df.groupby(['Name', pd.Grouper(key='startTime', freq='H')], as_index=False)
        .agg({'startTime': 'min', 'Name': 'first'})
)
# Get Max Time Per Hour
ends = (
    df.groupby(['Name', pd.Grouper(key='endTime', freq='H')], as_index=False)
        .agg({'endTime': 'max', 'Name': 'first'})
)
# Merge on Name and Same Hour
new_df = (
    starts.merge(
        ends,
        left_on=['Name', starts['startTime'].dt.hour],
        right_on=['Name', ends['endTime'].dt.hour])
        .drop('key_1', 1)[['startTime', 'endTime', 'Name']]
)
```

`new_df`:

```
                         startTime                          endTime Name
0 2021-06-14 23:20:03.182000+00:00 2021-06-14 23:58:59.752000+00:00    A
1 2021-06-14 23:52:18.720000+00:00 2021-06-14 23:54:40.218000+00:00    B
```

Comment: Henry, is the grouping to be within the same clock hour, or within one hour interval from last entry (which can be in different clock hour) ?

Comment: That's a good question. I went with start and end time in the same hour... But you are correct one hour from startTime is different than first and last in same hour. @SeaBean that's a question for the OP.